# Limit as x approaches zero?

Tags: limits

Do you know what the limit of $x \ln(\exp(1/x))$ is as $x$ approaches zero?  I don't know how to implement L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Have you tried applying l'Hopîtal?

Comment: Try replacing $x$ with $1/t$ and looking at the limits as $t\rightarrow\pm\infty$ of the resulting expression

Comment: Hmm, you must have edited the question because the "$\ln$" wasn't there before. So my previous comment is now invalid. Moreover, your expression is now identically $1$ except at $x=0$.

Comment: you are right! I should just delete this whole thread! You guys have been so helpful and I keep posting incorrect things and try  to fix them afterwards only to confuse everyone...THANK you for trying to help my confused self!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT.** What is $\log(e^x)$? What does that mean about your problem

> $\lim_{x \to 0} x\log(e^{1/x})=\lim_{x \to 0} x\cdot \frac{1}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} 1=1$

Comment: As an unrelated question. How can you hide the result?

Comment: @Umberto `>! ` produces a spoiler.

Comment: You guys are amazing.  Though in trying to simply my question I think I made a fool out of myself. I was wondering when I have a Bellman equation: \begin{equation}
\Gamma_{\theta}(v)(s,d) =\pi(s,d)
+\beta\displaystyle\int_{s'}b\log\displaystyle\sum_{d'=1}^{3}\left[\exp\left\{v(s',d')/b\right\}\right]f(s'|s,d)\mathrm{d}s'
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer. Very much appreciated.

Comment: It's the >! command. It needs to be a line apart from other lines surrounding it. Also, if you want to know someones commands to do something, you can always 'edit' the question just to see the commands used then just exit out. It's how I learned to do this and a few other cool tricks on the site. There's also a nice MathJax formatting section somewhere on here that I'm sure can also be found on the Math Meta page.

Comment: @lulumillcreek Ah, you oversimplified and didn't notice that makes it trivial? Happens.

Comment: Thanks @mathematics2x2life. You never stop learning :)

Comment: @DanielFischer, how do you get the gray-tinted region in which the spoiler lies?

Comment: @MPW I'm not sure what you're after. You get `inline code` by enclosing the text in backticks (aka grave accents). The spoiler in the answer, you get by starting a line, which is separated from pre- and succeeding lines by a blank line, with `>! `.

Comment: Ok--I will try your patience once more... Sorry! If I have the bellman equation above, and b approaches zero, then is it simple to know what the expression turns into?